# ADODB connection to .mdb file from excel 2013

Tags: excel, ms-access, adodb, vba

I hope someone can help.
I've developed an excel package that updates a .mdb access database through the connection string "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"
The database is shared.
I have a Mitel telephony system that checks the database every 10 seconds or so to check for a new entry.
The database is updated with

```
Dim q As New ADODB.Command
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "INSERT INTO tbl1LinkAuths (DateTimeAdded, DateEntered, AddedBy, REG,                                    OrderNo,AccountNumber, CentreNumber, EmailAddress, Callback, "
SQL = SQL & "MakeText, "...............

cn.Open cnDB
q.ActiveConnection = cn
q.CommandText = SQL
'Excecute the above SQL to insert the new job record
q.Execute


Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

Dim db As Access.Application
Set db = New Access.Application
db.Application.Visible = False
db.OpenCurrentDatabase "\\kffcis02\VWM Share\TelephonyDB.mdb", False
db.CloseCurrentDatabase
```

The INSERT statement updates the database fine, but I find I have to open and close the database to get it to update in time.

This package is used heavily by around 5 people at a time, making about 2 entries per minute.

It comes up with the error "file already in use", especially when using excel 2013, a lot of the time. I think this is because I have to open/close the database every time I update.

Does anybody know of a different way I can get the database to update quicker?
I've got the actual database setting to update ADODB every second and the database is shared.

I'm now desperate, as this package has went live. I didn't have any problems during testing because there wasn't as many people using it and none of them were on office 2013.

Comment: You shouldn't have to open and close the database. You should however make sure to close the connection you opened: `cn.close`

Comment: Thanks very much for that. Much appreciated. I really hope it's as easy at that.Set cn = Nothing

Comment: I meant to say, wouldn't set cn-nothing do the same thing. I've tried it without doing the open/close database, but the database doesn't update quick enough and when the telephony tries to read a new record, it can't see one.

Comment: No it wouldn't. From here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810829.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 "Even if the language you use has effective and reliable garbage collection, an instance of an open ADO Connection or Recordset object going out of scope does not equate to the Close method of that object being implicitly invoked. You must close it explicitly."

Comment: Sorry, on closer inspection, I have used cn.close in the code. So that's not the issue. I've tried again by adding another record and it definetely doesn't work unless the database is opened and closed again. Totally can't see what the issue is.

Comment: If you haven't posted the actual code you're using, it's pretty hard for us to try and help... ;) You don't really need a `Command` though - you could just execute the SQL directly from the `Connection`

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'd included all the necessary. The 'INSERT' statement works OK and so does the SELECT at the other end. It's the .mdb database not refreshing that's the problem.

Comment: You might try using `q.Execute Options:=adExecuteNoRecords` which should perform a little faster.

Comment: Thanks Rory. I've taken out the open/close database stuff and added your suggestion. It appears to be working, but I won't know for sure until no-one else is using the system and I can test myself. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong driver:  Assuming a reference to activex data objects...

```
dim conn as  adodb.connection    'module level variable
const DBNAME = "your name here"
const DBLOC = "Your dir here"

 Sub UpdateDb()

dim sql as string
openconnectionroutine
sql = "INSERT INTO tbl1LinkAuths (DateTimeAdded, DateEntered, AddedBy, "
'etc
'if you want to check it worked : otherwise ditch numrecs
 dim numrecs as long
conn.execute sql, numrecs
msgbox "You added " & numrecs & " records",vbokonly,"Done"

end sub

sub Openconnectionroutine() 
if conn is nothing then set conn = new adodb.connection
if conn.connectionstring = "" then
    conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" & _
                 "Dbq=" & DBNAME & ";" & _
                 "DefaultDir=" & DBLOC & ";" & _
                 "Uid=Admin;Pwd=;"
 end if
 if conn.state = adstateopen then
 else                
   conn.Open
 end if

End sub
```